Variance of a Continuous Stochastic Process
I have the following process:
$$
d \gamma(t) = - \lambda(\gamma(t) - \mu) dt + \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{t}} |\gamma(t) | dW(t) 
$$
I have, after a very long time, not found what $Var(\gamma(t))$ would be.
If we consider the discrete case $\gamma_t = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{t}} |\gamma_{t-1} | Z + \mu$, (such that Z is i.i.d. Normal(0,1)), the variance would be $\frac{\sigma^2\mu^2}{t-\sigma^2}$.
I know I can't use the discrete variance for the continuous one, but i cannot find what the analytical variance would be for $\gamma(t)$. Anything i have found is never in line with the monte carlo simulations for any $\mu, \sigma, t, \lambda$.
Thank you a lot!

What is the initial condition? Just like in ODEs, the answer will depend on the initial condition...

@SangchulLee, Apologies, forgot to mention. $\gamma(0) = \mu$

Here is a less rigorous but nevertheless justifiable computation for the mean and variance of $\gamma_t$.
We start from the SDE
$$ \gamma_{t+\mathrm{d}t} - \gamma_t
= \mathrm{d}\gamma_t
= -\lambda(\gamma_t - \mu) \, \mathrm{d}t + \frac{\sigma|\gamma_t|}{\sqrt{t}} \, \mathrm{d}W_t. \tag{1}\label{e:1} $$
Taking expectation to both sides and using the fact that $\mathrm{d}W_t$ is a centered gaussian variable independent of $\gamma_t$, we get
$$ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{E}[\gamma_t] = - \lambda (\mathbf{E}[\gamma_t] - \mu) \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{2}\label{e:2} $$
This is a first-order linear ODE for $\mathbf{E}[\gamma_t]$ and hence is easily solved:
$$ \mathbf{E}[\gamma_t] = \mu + (\mathbf{E}[\gamma_0] - \mu) e^{-\lambda t}. $$
Next we move on to computing the variance of $\mathbf{Var}(\gamma_t)$. Here, I will only cover the case where $\mathbf{E}[\gamma_{t_0}] = \mu$ for some $t_0 > 0$, which ensures that $\mathbf{E}[\gamma_t] = \mu$ for all $t > 0$. Now, we rearrange the SDE $\eqref{e:1}$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
\gamma_{t+\mathrm{d}t} &= (1 - \lambda \,\mathrm{d}t) \gamma_t + \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{t}} \, \mathrm{d}W_t + \mu\lambda \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{3}\label{e:3}
\end{align*}
Now we take variance to the both sides of $\eqref{e:3}$. Noting again that $\mathrm{d}W_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathrm{d}t)$ and is independent of $\gamma_t$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Var}(\gamma_{t+\mathrm{d}t})
&= (1 - \lambda \,\mathrm{d}t)^2 \mathbf{Var}(\gamma_t)
+ \frac{\sigma^2}{t} \mathbf{Var}(|\gamma_t|\mathrm{d}W_t)
+ \frac{(1 - \lambda \,\mathrm{d}t)\sigma}{\sqrt{t}} \underbrace{\mathbf{Cov}(\gamma_t, |\gamma_t| \mathrm{d}W_t)}_{=0} \\
&= (1 - 2\lambda \,\mathrm{d}t) \mathbf{Var}(\gamma_t)
+ \frac{\sigma^2}{t} \mathbf{E}[\gamma_t^2] \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}
Rearranging and invoking the assumption that $\mathbf{E}[\gamma_{t_0}] = \mu$ for some $t_0 \geq 0$ (and hence for all $t \geq t_0$ by $\eqref{e:2}$), the above equation simplifies as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{Var}(\gamma_t)}{\mathrm{d}t}
&= - \left(2\lambda - \frac{\sigma^2}{t} \right) \mathbf{Var}(\gamma_t) + \frac{\sigma^2 \mu^2}{t}. \tag{4}
\end{align*}
This equation has the solution of the form
$$ \mathbf{Var}(\gamma_t)
= e^{-2\lambda t} t^{\sigma^2} \left[ \mu^2 \sigma^2 \left( \int_{t_0}^{t} v^{-\sigma^2-1} e^{2 \lambda v} \, dv\right) + c_1 \right], \tag{5}\label{e:5} $$
where the value of $c_1$ is to be determined by the value of $\mathbf{Var}(\gamma_{t_0})$ (or its value at any timepoint $t \geq t_0$).
In the figure below, I ran a numerical simulation with $t_0 = 1$ and $\gamma_1 \equiv \mu$. In this simulation, I also set $\mu = 1$, $\lambda = 2$, and $\sigma = \frac{1}{3}$. The blue line is the sample variance of $\gamma_t$, as a function of $t$, computed using $10^4$ simulated sample paths. The orange dotted line is the exact solution $\eqref{e:5}$.

Below is Mathematica 14 code used for creating this figure:
\[Mu] = 1;
\[Lambda] = 2;
\[Sigma] = 1/3;
t0 = 0.001;
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[
      t] == -\[Lambda] (x[t] - \[Mu]) \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma]/
      Sqrt[t] Abs[x[t]] \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, \[Mu]}, t, 
   w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
data = ParallelTable[
   RandomFunction[proc, {t0, 5, 0.001}][[2, 1, 1]], {10000}];
Show[{
  ListPlot[Variance /@ Transpose[data], Joined -> True, 
   PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {t0, 5}],
  Plot[Exp[-2 \[Lambda]  t] t^\[Sigma]^2 \[Mu]^2 \[Sigma]^2 \
NIntegrate[ Exp[2 \[Lambda]  v]/v^(1 + \[Sigma]^2), {v, t0, t}], {t, 
    t0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97][2], Dashed], 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20]
  },
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Time (t)", "Variance"}
 ]
Clear[\[Mu], \[Lambda], \[Sigma]];


Might be a silly confirmation (but to make sure I understand), but for $c_1$, it would be changing as $t$ increases, and is defined by: $c_1 = -\mu^2\sigma^2\int^t_{t_0}v^{-\sigma^2-1}e^{2\lambda v}dv$?

Also on a tangent, may I ask to see your code for creating the plot?

@AlirezaGhaffarian, No, $c_1$ is a constant independent of $t$, and its value is determined by all the other parameters, $\mu$, $\sigma$, $\lambda$, as well as $\mathbf{Var}(\gamma_{t_1})$ for some $t_1>0$. (Here is caveat: When you plug $t_0=0$, the integral diverges unless $\sigma = 0$ or $\mu=0$. For me, this is implying that $\gamma_t$ started at a non-zero value at time $t=0$ must have infinite variance for all time $t$.)

@AlirezaGhaffarian, I used Mathematica for creating this plot. Although I included my code to my answer, it won't help that much if you don't have Mathematica.

I am a bit confused. Maybe I misunderstood. Then in the integral, what is the upper bound $t$?
Also, many thanks for the code. I do have Mathematica with my university.

@AlirezaGhaffarian, The variance of $\gamma_t$ certainly depends on the value of time $t$ (as well as other parameters), just like the variance in the discrete case $\frac{\sigma^2\mu^2}{t^2-\sigma^2}$ is a function of time $t$. Unfortunately, it turns out that $\mathbf{Var}(\gamma_t)$ in the continuous case cannot be written in an elementary way. Instead, we can write it as an expression involving an integral, which is the formula $\eqref{e:5}$.

This formula $\eqref{e:5}$ involves an unspecified constant $c_1$, but this is no problem because its value can be determined if you know the value of $\mathbf{Var}(\gamma_t)$ at a given time $t_0$. The upshot is that $\eqref{e:5}$ becomes $$\mathbf{Var}(\gamma_t)
= e^{-2\lambda t} t^{\sigma^2} \left[ \mu^2 \sigma^2 \left( \int_{t_0}^{t} v^{-\sigma^2-1} e^{2 \lambda v} , dv\right) + \frac{\mathbf{Var}(\gamma_{t_0})}{e^{-2\lambda t_0} t_0^{\sigma^2}} \right], \tag{5'}$$ Just check that both sides coincide when $t = t_0$. :)

Ahh right! Now I get you. And as an example, when we have $\gamma_1 = \mu$, then $c_1 = 0$, thus left with one large multiplication.
Many thanks Sangchul . Really appreciate it

@AlirezaGhaffarian That's right! :) A final comment for the numerical simulation: As we make $t_0$ closer and closer to the zero (starting around $t_0\approx0.001$ as I tested), it seems the simulation begins significantly deviating from the analytic formula. I guess this is another manifestation of the fact that the variance becomes infinite if $\gamma_t$ has started at $t_0=0$. The initial condition $t_0=0$ is also problematic in the discrete case, which also hints that something wild happens as $t_0 \approx 0$.

Yeah that is something I noted while trying to simulate at 0 for discrete case. I just came up with the condition that it should be equal to $\mu$, hence variance is nil. I guess I expected for the continuous case to be a bit more well behaved. But now I have learnt to not make such frivolous assumptions...
